# Conditions in ElasticSearch queries

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, database, nosql

I'm new to ElasticSearch. It seems pretty awesome, but I'm extremely confused by the JSON-based query language.

I am going to use ES as a document store. I am interested in making queries such "get all documents where age = 25", or "get all documents where name = 'john' and city = 'london'". However I have yet to understand how this can be done.

I can do this:

{
    "query": {
            "match": { 
                     "age": "25"
              }
      }
}

But is this what I'm looking for? I think this would also return documents where `age` is "25 apples".

Please explain how one can issue such simpe queries against ES.

Comment: You can use these things instead.. First set your age field as not_analysed in your mapping. Second In your mapping define a strict dynamic mapping  with type long for age field. Third ensure the data you have in that particular type is correct, as its giving you the wrong data from that particular field it means your data is wrong and use term query instead of match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `age` matching you can use `term Query`. [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) looks for exact match.

```
{
"query": {
  "term": {
     "age": "25"
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're afraid of the query DSL, you might be less afraid to use the [query string mini-language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax) (close to the Lucene query language) [passed directly in the URI](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) with the `q=` query string parameter, it might be a bit simpler to learn and event though it has some limitations, it allows you to go a long way.

For instance, in order to query all documents with age = 25, you 'd do it like this:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?q=age:25'
```

For all documents with age between 25 and 30:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?q=age:[25 TO 30]'
```

For all documents with age between 25 and 30 and the country `US`:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?q=age:[25 TO 30] AND country:us'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 To get all documents where (name = john and city = london).You can use following command:


    GET /bank/account/_search?q=firstname:Rodriquez%20AND%20age:31

     Or,You can also try Filters:

     GET /demo/post/_search?pretty=true
     {
       "query": {
         "filtered": {
             "filter": {
                 "and": [
                {
                "term": {
                  "name": "john"
                }
              },
              {
             "term": {
             "city": "london"
                    }
                  }
             ]
            }
           }
          }
        }
```

Comment: You can use these things instead.. First set your age field as not_analysed in your mapping. Second In your mapping define a strict dynamic mapping  with type long for age field. Third ensure the data you have in that particular type is correct, as its giving you the wrong data from that particular field it means your data is wrong.